# Create a New Column Based on the Value of two Columns in Pandas with conditionals

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, calculated-columns

I have a dataframe with two different columns I need to use to calculate a score:

| id | Pos | Player | GW | VP | Final | Drop | TournamentPoints |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | Alessio Bianchi | 2 | 7.0 | 5.0 | NaN |
| 1 | 2 | 2 | Gianluca Bianco | 2 | 7.0 | 0.0 | NaN |
| 2 | 3 | 2 | Sara Rossi | 1 | 5.0 | 0.0 | NaN |
| 3 | 4 | 2 | Gabriele Verdi | 1 | 4.5 | 0.0 | NaN |
| 4 | 5 | 2 | Luca Gialli | 1 | 3.0 | 0.0 | NaN |

Tournament points is calculated from GW and VP with a formula:

```
df['TournamentPoints'] = ((number_of_players / 10) * (df["VP"] + 1)) + (df['GW'] * x)
```

Where `number_of_players` and X are calculated previously.

HoweverI need another step:

1. add 50 to the row with the highest value in "Final" columns (in this case Alessio Bianchi).
2. if two rows have the same value in "Final" and it's the highest, only the row with the lowest "Pos" must receive the 50 boost.

Any suggestion? Thanks in advance

I already tried .apply() and .map() methods without success

Comment: Is Pos unique? If not, what should happen if there are two max Final with a same Pos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Pos is already sorted, you can use [`idxmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html), this will select the first row that has the maximum value:

```
df['TournamentPoints'] = ((number_of_players / 10) * (df["VP"] + 1)) + (df['GW'] * x)

df.loc[df['Final'].idxmax(), 'TournamentPoints'] += 50
```

If Pos is not sorted:

```
df.loc[df.sort_values(by='Pos')['Final'].idxmax(), 'TournamentPoints'] += 50
```